# How to pass a link as parameter via route expressjs

Tags: express, routes

According to the document, when passing parameter through get method on express, we can easily use:

```
localhost:8080/example/:first_parameter
```

then get the value by:

```
let first_parameter = req.params.first_parameter;
```

However when the first parameter is a link, something like:

```
localhost:8080/example/"http://something.net"
```

it wil be error. So How to pass a link as parameter via route expressjs

Comment: I think you should encode `http://something.net` as `http%3A%2F%2Fsomething.net` without double quote

Comment: Why don't you use POST instead of GET ? it would solve the problem without encoding or something

Comment: @developerbh yes, I did use the POST method and it ran successfully. But in this case I just want to use GET for beautiful url :)

Comment: @KeitaroUrashima alright then try to use regex to change http:// and (.)net or com before passing the value as a parameter, and in the other side (server side) reverse the regex to get the real passed parameter (URL) .. u c what I mean?